# Send sql request with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table and index.php. I can fill the table column with a sql query. The query doesnt include sorting. Later I added a button for sorting. When I click the button I want to do sorting with query.

```
$query="SELECT city, street, city_v,street_v,id_seq_x,page_title, 
page_url, uniq_key, price, currency, to_char(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date,situation, 
situation_v, categories,categories_v FROM information";
```

İt is my query. I filled table column. Later I want to run this query.

```
$query2="order by price";
$query_last=$query.$query2;
```

When I click the button How can I run this query? For example:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  window.location.href="index.php?sort="+$query_last;});
```

I hope I could have explained enough.

Comment: You need to put a space between both parts of the query. In addition, your syntax for concatenating strings in PHP is incorrect. You need to use `.` not `+`.

Comment: instead of posting back to the server and running yet another database query just to sort the data you already have, then why not just take advantage of client-side sorting? since you are already using jquery, then you should take a look at https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to extract the value of sort from your url by using the `$_GET` variable.

In your case this would be:

```
$query2 = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : false;
```

If sort is empty, `$query2` would be false. If not it will have this value: **order%020by%20price**

This query would not work, unless you would `explode` the string on `%20` and after that implode it again to add spaces between the words (Well, I suppose; I'm not sure if %20 would be parsed as a space)...

So I would suggest you to use it this way:

```
$query2 = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : false;
```

Now the jquery after you click the button:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    window.location = 'index.php?sort=true'; 
});
```

Then you could check with an if else statement if the sorting is true:

```
if ($query2) {
    $query2 = 'order by price'; // re-assign the variable another value
    $sql = $query . ' ' . $query2 // Notice the space between the queries
}
```

After that you could use the new formatted query to extract the data.